# NER - Entity Recognition - Country Filter

Tags: python, entity, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to extract Geo-relevant Info from an Excel file with spacy. It works to extract all Entities, but I just need the Geo-Data and don´t find a way to filter the entities.

```py
import pandas as pd
import spacy

sp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", usecols=["Bio", "Author"])
df.head(1)
df=df.fillna('')
#df['Bio']
doc = df.values.tolist()
#print (doc)
#sp(', '.join(doc[0])).ents
for entry in doc:
    #print('Current entry\n {}'.format(entry))
    for entity in sp(', '.join(entry)).ents:
        print(entity.text, entity.label)
```

Currently, the output looks like:

```
Munich 384

Germany 384

Venezuela 384

London 384

Portrait | 9191306739292312949

 ℍ  ​ 383

  ​ 394

Visited: 383

 384

 392
```

At the end I want to write the Geo-relevant Entities (if existing) back to the user´s row in a new column **"Location"** in the `csv`.

I would appreciate your help very much, with kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can filter for the "LOC" or "GPE" entity provided by the spacy language model. However, be aware that the NER language model needs to have a sentence contex to be able to predict the location entities.

```py
sp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
# loop over every row in the 'Bio' column
for text in df['Bio'].tolist():
    # use spacy to extract the entities
    doc = sp(text)
    for ent in doc.ents:    
        # check if entity is equal 'LOC' or 'GPE'
        if ent.label_ in ['LOC', 'GPE']:
            print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Here the link to the spacy NER documentation: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

**EDIT**

Here is the full list of English spacy entity types from the documentation:

- PERSON   People, including fictional.  NORP  Nationalities or religious or political groups.
- FAC  Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.
- ORG  Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.
- GPE  Countries, cities, states.
- LOC  Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water.
- PRODUCT  Objects, vehicles, foods, etc. (Not services.)
- EVENT    Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.
- WORK_OF_ART  Titles of books, songs, etc.
- LAW  Named documents made
  into laws.
- LANGUAGE Any named language.
- DATE Absolute or relative dates or periods.
- TIME Times smaller than a day.
- PERCENT  Percentage, including ”%“.
- MONEY    Monetary values, including unit.
- QUANTITY Measurements, as of weight or distance.
- ORDINAL  “first”, “second”, etc.
- CARDINAL Numerals that do not fall under another type.

Source: https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities

Comment: Thank you, well I used GPE instead of LOC and this worked out... Sentence context is given - at least a bit :-)

Comment: Ah correct, the "GPE" is more suitable; from the docs: GPE = Countries, cities, states, LOC = Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water. I updated my answer.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solved your question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `entity.label_` (with an underscore) to see the string version of the entity labels, which might help you filter a little. The default English NER model (trained on web/newspaper text) might not do well on this kind of text, though, since it doesn't really know anything about emojis or some of the other unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull out the NER labels and filter on that. You can grab the labels with something like:

```
entities=[]
for i, current_doc in enumerate(df['the_text_col']):
  doc = spacy_model_name(current_doc)
  for entity in doc.ents:
    entities.append((entity.label_, df.index[i]))
```

After this make `entities` a df, add an index, and join back to your processed DF that has the NER info, if you'd like. From there you can filter with `contains` and get just the rows that have the label you want.